# published TStrings-property is not loaded for custom control

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, deserialization

I wrote a `TListBox`-like control (similar to [Doctor Bob's SpeedBox](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/speedbox.htm)).

It runs fine, except one issue: Strings assigned to property `Items` are not loaded into the `TListBox` field on startup. I found out, that my procedure `SetItem` is not called on creation because the component reader assigns the strings with `TStrings.Add`.

The control's source code:

```
unit HKS.Controls.FilterListBox;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  THKSFilterListBox = class(TWinControl)
  strict private
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FItems: TStrings;
    FListBox: TListBox;
    procedure SetItems(const Value: TStrings);
    procedure ReInitListBoxItems;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property Items: TStrings read FItems write SetItems;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics, Winapi.Windows;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('HKS', [THKSFilterListBox]);
end;

{ THKSFilterListBox }

constructor THKSFilterListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FItems := TStringList.Create;

  FEdit  := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Parent    := Self;

  FListBox := TListBox.Create(Self);
  FListBox.Parent := Self;

  ReInitListBoxItems; // has no effect since data is not loaded yet
end;

destructor THKSFilterListBox.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FListBox);
  FreeAndNil(FEdit);
  FreeAndNil(FItems);
  inherited;
end;

procedure THKSFilterListBox.ReInitListBoxItems;
var
  LFilterText: String;
begin
  LFilterText := AnsiUpperCase(Trim(FEdit.Text));

  FListBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    if LFilterText <> '' then
    begin
      // some filter routine
    end else
      FListBox.Items.Assign(FItems);
  finally
    FListBox.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure THKSFilterListBox.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
const
  cEditHeightAddon = 12;
  cMargin          =  2;
var
  LListBoxTop: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FEdit.SetBounds(0, 0, Self.Width, Abs(Font.Height) + cEditHeightAddon);
  LListBoxTop := FEdit.BoundsRect.Bottom + cMargin;
  FListBox.SetBounds(0, LListBoxTop, Self.Width, Self.Height - LListBoxTop);
end;

// is not called on startup because items are added one by one with "TStrings.Add"
procedure THKSFilterListBox.SetItems(const Value: TStrings);
begin
  FItems.Assign(Value);
  ReInitListBoxItems;
end;

end.
```

I need my very own instance of `Items` because not all items shall be shown, depending on what filter string is in `FEdit.Text`.

**Is there any way to call `ReInitListBoxItems` after properties have been loaded from dfm?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to call ReInitListBoxItems after properties have been loaded from dfm?

Override the component's [`Loaded`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Loaded) method.

> Initializes the component after the form file has been read into
>   memory.
>
> Do not call the protected Loaded method. The streaming system calls
>   this method after it loads the component's form from a stream.
>
> When the streaming system loads a form or data module from its form
>   file, it first constructs the form component by calling its
>   constructor, then reads its property values from the form file. After
>   reading all the property values for all the components, the streaming
>   system calls the Loaded methods of each component in the order the
>   components were created. This gives the components a chance to
>   initialize any data that depends on the values of other components or
>   other parts of itself.

```
type
  THKSFilterListBox = class(TWinControl)
    ...
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
    ...
  end;

procedure THKSFilterListBox.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  ReInitListBoxItems;
end;
```

Comment: You should also assign an `OnChange` event handler to `FItems`, or even derive a new class from `TStrings` and override its virtual methods, instead of using `TStringList`. Either way, this will allow your component to react to changes to the `Items` property in code at runtime after the component has been loaded. For instance, `HKSFilterListBox1.Items.Add('...')` will not trigger `SetItems()`, either. So you would need to detect the addition so you can update the ListBox accordingly.

Comment: Great Answer, @David, and very useful comment, @Remy! I searched for something like `Loaded` but, concerning Remy's comment, I set the `OnChange` event handler, now.